# error al crear pdf con pdfmaker en nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Estoy llamando a la función **createDocument()** desde un endpoint en la carpeta controller en node el cual ejecuta una funcion. Esta funcion está declarada en un archivo llamado **pdf.js** en una carpeta llamada **pdfs**. \

archivo pdf.js:

```
const pdfPrinter = require("pdfmake");
const fs = require("fs");
const fonts = require("./fonts");
const styles = require("./styles");

//const {content} = require("./pdfContent");
module.exports=function(){
let content = [
    {
        text: "primer parrafo",
        style: "header",
    },
    "segundo parrafo" ,
    {
        text:"tercer parrafo", style: "header",
    }
]

let docDefinition = {
    content: content,
    styles: styles,
};

const printer = new pdfPrinter(fonts);

let pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("pdfs/pdfTest.pdf"));
pdfDoc.end();
}
```

Al acceder al endpoint el error que me arroja es el siguiente: \

> node:events:498
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\HumanResources\backend\HumanResources\backend\server\pdfs\pdfTest.pdf'
> Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
> at WriteStream.onerror (node:internal/streams/readable:773:14)
> at WriteStream.emit (node:events:520:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {   errno: -4058,   code:
> 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'open',   path:
> 'C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\HumanResources\backend\HumanResources\backend\server\pdfs\pdfTest.pdf'
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me imagino que tiene que ver con un problema de sintaxis al no encontrar la ruta que estableces. Y si pruebas esto: pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/pdfs/pdfTest.pdf"));

De cualquier manera como recomendación principal y alternativamente, recomiendo la librería html-pdf.

Comment: Efectivamente era un error con establecer la ruta en donde se generaba, muchas gracias;)